# D2010 TPanel / TFrame / TGroupBox / Other - Which is lightest?

Tags: delphi

I have a TabControl, and I am using a TPanel to group my controls for each tab in D2010. Out of TPanel / TFrame / TGroupBox / Other which is the lightest weight control I can use for this? I only need to set its size and visibility thats all. Ty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on the light trip, I guess you are on the right path with TPanel or TGroupBox, while TFrame would allow to modularize your app a little more, but that depends.

Answer (score 4):

Your question sound like you want to use `TPageControl` instead.

It is in fact, a `TabControl` with attached `Panels` to each tab.